# Developing game progress screen

Tags: ios, iphone, levels, spritekit

I'm developing an application for iPhone with a screen where the user will track his progress. Something like so, as seen in the Two Dots game:

[image]

Currently I plan on creating this using constraints and size classes. But I feel its too much of work for each screen size. I've set a background `UIImageView` and I place different circles, manually hardcoding the position. The curved path in my case is made of a texture. So I can't plot it using Bezier Curves either.

Is there an easier way to do it? Perhaps using SpriteKit or Cocos2D-x?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SpriteKit, or Cocos2D, so I can't answer that question.  However you should be able to accommodate any screen size if you use percentages. If you calculate the percent of pixels where each circle is placed in regards to your original image, you can use this value to calculate the placement of each marker in the target resolution.

For example, in the image you posted, the top left corner of circle 35, looks to be at (roughly) 55% of the screens width, and 45% of the screens height. If these values are accurate, you can calculate the screen position in any resolution very easily.

```
x = screenWidth * circlePositionWidthPercantage;
y = screenHeight * circlePositionHeightPercantage;
```